# How can I select items in ListA that have a property that matches an item's property in ListB?

Tags: c#

I have a `List<A>`, where A contains a property called `TypeId`, and a `List<B>`, where B also contains a property called `TypeId`

I want to select all items from `List<A>` where `List<B>` contains an item where `B.TypeId == A.TypeId`

```
ListA.Add(new A { TypeId = 1 });
ListA.Add(new A { TypeId = 2 });
ListA.Add(new A { TypeId = 3 });

ListB.Add(new B { TypeId = 3 });
ListB.Add(new B { TypeId = 4 });
ListB.Add(new B { TypeId = 1 });

???? // Should return items 1 and 3 only
```

What is the most efficient way of doing this?

I know its something simple, but my brain is feeling stupid today....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using LINQ, it's rather simple using the Join method.

```
var join = ListA.Join(ListB, la => la.TypeId, lb => lb.TypeId, (la, lb) => la);
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are trying to do an intersect operation, and it should be possible with the [Intersect](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb460136%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) Extension. One advantage here is that intersect will run in O(m + n). 
Example program :

```
class Program
{
    class Bar
    {
        public Bar(int x)
        {
            Foo = x;
        }
        public int Foo { get; set; }
    }

    class BarComparer : IEqualityComparer<Bar>
    {
        public bool Equals(Bar x, Bar y)
        {
            return x.Foo == y.Foo;
        }

        public int GetHashCode(Bar obj)
        {
            return obj.Foo;
        }

    }
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var list1 = new List<Bar>() { new Bar(10), new Bar(20), new Bar(30)};
        var list2 = new List<Bar>() { new Bar(10),  new Bar(20) };
        var result = list1.Intersect(list2, new BarComparer());

        foreach (var item in result)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(item.Foo);
        }
    }
}
```